# Use a dynamic operator inside a if on javascript

Tags: javascript, operators

I'm creating a filter. On this i have the **operation field** and the **value field**.

The **select** select contains "bigger than","bigger or equals to", "lower than", etc...

The **point** input receive value from **1.00** to **10.00**.

Something like this:

```
<select class="operator" name="operator">
    <option value='>' selected='selected'> bigger </option>
    <option value='<'> lower </option>
    <option value='=='> equals </option>
</select>
<input class="points" name="points" value="">
```

and i'm looking for a result closer to this on submit:

```
var operator = $('.operator').val();
var points = $('.points').val();

//in case that "bigger(>)" was selected and points was 6
//if (10 > 5) { 
if (10 operator points ) {
    /*do something*/
}
```

i tried things like this without success:

```
if (10 eval(operator) points ) { /*do something*/ }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 if(eval(10 + operator + points))
```

You have to build up a whole operation.